# How to correctly pass YUV_420_888 Image Buffer from Java through JNI to OpenCV, accounting for stride/padding

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-camera

I'm trying to convert the image data from an Android device from YUV_420_888 to an RGB matrix on the C++ side. On some devices, this is working flawlessly. On a Note 10, the image comes out looking like this:

[image]

My guess here is that the stride is causing this issue. How do I remove this extra data and then pass the correct buffer through JNI?

Here is the Java code:

```
IntBuffer rgb = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().asIntBuffer();
NativeLib.passImageBuffer(rgb);
```

And here is the C++ code:

```
cv::Mat outputRGB;
cv::cvtColor(cv::Mat(height+height/2, width, CV_8UC1, inputRGB), outputRGB, CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);
```

I've tried some different image formats on the C++ side, but they all come back with the same band on the side of the screen.

I've implemented [this answer](https://answers.opencv.org/question/211278/problem-converting-yuv-to-rgb-imagereader-from-android-camera2-using-opencv-output-image-is-in-grayscale/), in order to remove the extra padding, but the image that is passed ends up being completely green. Do some corresponding edits need to be made to the C++ code? I've tried using a 3 channel format, but that crashes at runtime. I'm thinking that since passing the buffer works with the 1 channel matrix on phones that have 8 bits per pixel, that it should be possible to do that with the note 10?

```
            Image.Plane Y = image.getPlanes()[0];
            Image.Plane U = image.getPlanes()[1];
            Image.Plane V = image.getPlanes()[2];

            int[] rgbBytes = new int[image.getHeight()*image.getWidth()*4];
            int idx = 0;
            ByteBuffer yBuffer = Y.getBuffer();
            int yPixelStride = Y.getPixelStride();
            int yRowStride = Y.getRowStride();
            ByteBuffer uBuffer = U.getBuffer();
            int uPixelStride = U.getPixelStride();
            int uRowStride = U.getRowStride();
            ByteBuffer vBuffer = V.getBuffer();
            int vPixelStride = V.getPixelStride();
            int vRowStride = V.getRowStride();

            ByteBuffer rgbBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(rgb.limit());
            for (int row = 0; row < image.getHeight(); row++) {
              for (int col = 0; col < image.getWidth(); col++) {
                int y = yBuffer.get(col*yPixelStride + row*yRowStride) & 0xff;
                int u = uBuffer.get(col/2*uPixelStride + row/2*uRowStride) & 0xff;
                int v = vBuffer.get(col/2*vPixelStride + row/2*vRowStride) & 0xff;

                int y1 = ((19077 << 8) * y) >> 16;
                int r = (y1 + (((26149 << 8) * v) >> 16) - 14234) >> 6;
                int g = (y1 - (((6419 << 8) * u) >> 16) - (((13320 << 8) * v) >> 16) +  8708) >> 6;
                int b = (y1 + (((33050 << 8) * u) >> 16) - 17685) >> 6;

                if (r < 0) r = 0;
                if (g < 0) g = 0;
                if (b < 0) b = 0;
                if (r > 255) r = 255;
                if (g > 255) g = 255;
                if (b > 255) b = 255;
                byte pixel = (byte)(0xff000000 + b + 256 * (g + 256 * r));
                rgbBuffer.put(pixel);
              }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this repo
https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/yuvToMat/

It supports different formats (YUV420, NV12) and variety of pixel and row strides.

Comment: I must add that I found this lib doesn't work on some devices with some image sizes. I described issue here https://github.com/quickbirdstudios/yuvToMat/issues/5
The problem is sometimes width != rowStride